# Enabling logging in event viewer through Wix

Tags: wix

Need to enable logging in event viewer via my installer. Been using:

```
> wevtutil im "path\...etwManifest.man" /mf:"path\....etwManifest.dll" /rf:"path\...etwManifest.dll" /sl: <name>
```

to enable logging via CMD, but would like to integrate into Wix. Also need to enable analytic and debug logs.

Started with:

```
<Component Id="etwManifest.dll">
            <File Id="etwManifest.dll" Directory="ProgramFilesFolder" KeyPath="yes"
                Source="!(wix._NTTREE)\path\....etwManifest.dll" />
    </Component>
        <Component Id="etwManifest.man">
            <File Id="etwManifest.man" Directory="ProgramFilesFolder" KeyPath="yes"
          Source="!(wix._NTTREE)\path\....man">
      <util:EventManifest  MessageFile="[etwManifest.dll]"  ResourceFile="[etwManifest.dll]"></util:EventManifest>
    </File>
```

I can't see how to enable the analytic and debug logging, and I haven't tried running it yet, but I don't think this will work. Any pointers?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason that MSI logging is not sufficient?